# Visual Studio 2010 Tools for office runtime - end of the lifecycle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

The support for "Visual Studio 2010 Tools for office runtime" has been stopped and because of this we are currently looking for alternatives.

The following link describes that the newer office versions (2013,2016) require "Visual Studio 2010 Tools for office runtime":

See "Required runtime on end-user computer":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/running-solutions-in-different-versions-of-microsoft-office?view=vs-2019

But now that VSTO 2010 is no longer supported with Visual Studio 2010, the question is which runtime should we use for developing Office 2013 and 2016 plugins?
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2010

Comment: Where did you find the information that "Visual Studio 2010 tools for office runtime" has been stopped? "VSTO 2010 Runtime" and "Visual Studio 2010" are different things. And yes, there is only one runtime (2010, aka V4).

Comment: thanks for your answer! Yes i know but the "VSTO 2010 runtime" follows the "Visual Studio 2010" lifecycle which ended in July 2020. The following link describes all of the editions which are affected => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2010 (In our case its the "Tools for Office System 4.0 Runtime) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[MSFT posted an official update to this yesterday](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/lifecycle-policy-is-unclear-due-to-name-of-redistr/1230790?from=email&viewtype=all#T-N1434916)

In a nutshell, the support lifetime of VSTO will match that of the parent product, which still includes all versions of VS, up to and including 2019. They have a backlog item to remove the 2010 designation to remove confusion.